# Is no one here doing philosophy. Really?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, voting

I think it makes no sense to say that no one is doing philosophy here, I think it is hypocritical. How can you talk about philosophy without "doing" it?

I think that there should be more weight on avoiding original research and a lot less on "not doing philosophy".

Now, if I was being downvoted (yay!) for only asking questions that you didn't know any research on, that would be diffferent.

Comment: What do you hold to be the difference between "original research" and "doing philosophy"? You want more emphasis on one and less on the other, yet those concepts seem the same to me.

Comment: they're not identical tho are they, i can do original research into literature e.g.. AND my point was that YOU HAVE TO DO PHILOSOPHY TO READ AND UNDERSTAND IT.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify yourself by providing some examples. Also, the first paragraph of this question seems to be a different question from the title, and would belong on the main site (if anywhere). What exactly is your question?

Comment: ok to follow an argument about say kant you have to reproduce it without just verbal comprehension in the same way that you can know what notes are played without understanding music

Comment: This has been discussed elsewhere:

http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-this-site-for-doing-philosophy-or-discussing-philosophy

http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-this-site-be-restricted-to-academic-answers-only

http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-we-restrict-this-site-to-academic-questions-only-or-target-a-more-casual

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"the question is not grounded in philosophy enough to be a good fit; we like questions that reference specific expertise rather than simple generate a long list of opinions."

I have little to add to this response from a stoic, to another question; make of it what you will.

Answer (score 0):

I read that philosophy is the search for truth. If posing questions is a means to search for truth it is philosophy. So a site dedicated to asking and answering questions is philosophy, at least philosophical enquiry.

My reference is Aristotle. I hope he qualifies as a useful source....

Comment: yeah i tend to agree, sorry :D !